# Physical address of kernel code

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, x86-64

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535379/do-kernel-pages-get-swapped-out) says the kernel page is unswappable.

Then what I wonder is the physical address of kernel code is always calculatable from the virtual address when I disable KASLR (especially, in x86_64)?

Let's assume PHYSICAL_START in configuration is 0x1000000, and the start virtual address of <_text> section is 0xffffffff81000000.
I think the physical address of every kernel code is (vaddr - 0xffffffff81000000 + 0x1000000)

Is this always true? If not, is this true when I use defconf (except disabling KASLR)?

---

Updated:
I'm modifying QEMU itself for the research purpose. I have to read a guest kernel code instruction. I only use a vmlinux image (meaning, I don't load additional modules).
I have the virtual address and I tried to read a memory using this virtual address.
For somewhat reason, I failed to read a memory with the virtual address, but I succeeded to read a memory with a physical address (calculated by my hand).
So If I can calculate the physical address in the above way, I think this way could be a shortcut (even it isn't a good idea).
I know there are monitor and gdbserver and they work well. But I don't know they are the options.

Comment: Why do you ask? From what perspective (user process, or kernel code, e.g. module)?

Comment: Look for the `System RAM` / `Kernel code` start address in **/proc/iomem**.  You'll need to have root privileges to get actual values.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I updated the question. Is it enough?

Comment: You might also find [kernel newbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) mailing list helpful. A bunch of the kernel folks hang there.